# Office 365 unified API (preview) - Disable Group Welcome Message

Tags: office365

Is there any way of disabling the welcome message when a user is subscribed to a Unified Group?

Background:  We're having our system automatically add and remove users to/from groups as they work on specific projects.  We have people working on a project for a couple days, then they move onto other projects, and then a week or two later will come back to the project.

We would like to disable these notifications ("You've joined the **** group") so that our people aren't flooded with these notifications each time they're re-added.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:  Use SPAM Filter.  In the SPAM settings, set up an organization-wide filter that looks for chunks of the text in the subject / body of that default welcome email (might have to enable advanced options to accomplish this), then set it to delete these emails without notification.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to disable only the welcome message via the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell to do this (need to connect to Exchange Online before):

```
# connect to exchange online
$credential = Get-Credential
$exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $credential -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $exchangeSession -DisableNameChecking

# turn off welcome message
Set-UnifiedGroup "<groupname>" -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled:$false

# clean session
Remove-PSSession $exchangeSession
```